# How can i loop in ordered list tage with php while

Tags: php

i would like to loop in  tag using php while:

```
  <?php 
    $x = 1; 

    while($x <= 5) {
  ?>
  <ol><li></li></ol>
  <?php
   $x++;
  } 
 ?>
```

And i would like to output the list with serial like that:
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
Not like:
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.

Answer (score 2):

The ordered list tag should be outside the loop otherwise you're making a new list every time you loop through

> $x

This should work:

```
<?php 
    $x = 1; 
    echo "<ol>";
    while($x <= 5) {
    echo "<li>" + $x + "</li>";
    $x++;
 }
 echo "</ol>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `<ol>` tag outside the `while` loop.

Try

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
    echo '<ol>';
    while($x <= 5)
    {
        ?>
        <li>Text</li>
        <?php
        ++$x;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<ol>` tags should be outside the loop. What you basically are doing is creating a new list each loop iteration. This should work:

```
<ol>
<?php 
    $x = 1; 
    while($x <= 5) {
      ?>
      <li></li>
      <?php
      $x++;
    } 
?>
</ol>
```

Comment: @H.Ali this should be the accepted answer as the other similar answer adds "Text" to the given code without reason.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this one

```
<ol>
    <?php 
        $x = 1; 
        while($x <= 5) {
            echo "<li>" . $x;
            $x++;
            echo "</li>";
        }

     ?>
 </ol>
```